# update the form with entered email id from login page

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, phpmyadmin

I m trying to login page using email id and password. login page redirects to application form  where user as to enter all the details and the details as to be saved in the email id entered during the login. the email id which is entered in the login page should be posted to application form and it as to be in readonly. I m not able to post the email id from login page to application form
 How can i do this?

here is a table
name|email|password|surname|mname|........
name,email,password will be entered into db using signup form
 here is the code

login.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{          
    if($_POST['action']=="login")
    {

        $email =mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['password']);
        $strSQL = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from cvformat where email='".$email."' and password='".md5($password)."'");
        $Results = mysqli_fetch_array($strSQL);
        if(count($Results)>=1)
        {
           echo "<script>window.open('form.php','_self')</script>";
        }
        else
        {
                echo "<script>alert('Invalid ID or Password!')</script>";
        }           
    }
```

form.php

```
<div id="header" align="center"><img src="images/header.png" alt="" /></div>
    <form name="XIForm" id="XIForm" method="POST" action="pdf/pdf1.php">
<table border="0px" cellspacing="0px" cellspacing="10px" align="center" width="700px">



<tr>
<td style="width:200px;"><div class="label"><b >Surname, Name:</b></div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" style="width:250px; padding:5px;"/></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:200px;"><div class="label"><label><b >Middle Initial:</b></label></div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="mname" id="mname" style="width:250px; padding:5px;"/></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:200px;"><div class="label"><label><b >Email ID</b></label></div></td>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input" size="40" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['email'])) { echo $_GET['email']; } ?>" readonly> <br /> <br />

</tr>
```

pdf.php

```
$surname  = "";
    $mname = "";
    $email = "";
if($_REQUEST["formType"] == "reg") {

    $surname  = $_REQUEST["surname"];
    $mname  = $_REQUEST["mname"];
$email = $_REQUEST["email"];
$formType = "reg";
}

$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$db = "cv";
//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
mysqli_select_db($db,$dbhandle) or die('cannot select db');


if(isset($_POST['update'])){

mysqli_query("UPDATE cvformat SET surname='".$_POST['surname']."', mname='".$_POST['mname']."',dob='".$_POST['dob']."', city='".$_POST['city']."',region='".$_POST['region']."',country='".$_POST['country']."', diocese='".$_POST['diocese']."', nationality='".$_POST['nationality']."', fname='".$_POST['fname']."',mothername='".$_POST['mothername']."', edate='".$_POST['edate']."', city2='".$_POST['city2']."', region2='".$_POST['region2']."',country2='".$_POST['country2']."',datef='".$_POST['datef']."',dateo='".$_POST['dateo']."',city3='".$_POST['city3']."',region3='".$_POST['region2']."' WHERE email='".$_POST['hidden']."'") or die(mysqli_error()); 


 };
```

What is the problem with the code.

Comment: Q: Why are you using `mysqli_` in one code, then `mysql_` in the other?

Comment: no..other values have to be filled in the form

Comment: i want the value from the login form to be displayed into another form.

Comment: login.php is the login form from which the email id entered as to be redirted to form.php

Comment: i dont know how to use $_session.I m new to php

Comment: I have done the same think the email id doesnt get posted to form.php.. Even the db doesnt get updated with the entered values

Answer (score 0):

Your Window.open script refreshes the page, as the page gets refreshed the post value become untrue.

Calling script inside PHP is not suggested by many coders.

If I was you, I wouldnot refresh the page. instead

```
//if user submited the form
if(isset($_POST['action']) {
  //fetch user input values
  //verify the input values with database
  if($loginBool){
    //show content after login
  } else {
    //show error form
  }
} else {
  //show login form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Session variable is most simple and wise solution. So need some changes

In your `login.php`

On the top after php tag paste this line

```
session_start();
```

and also after this line.

```
$email =mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['email']);
```

Add one line for storing email into session variable. look below

```
$_SESSION['email']= $email;
```

Then in the `form.php`, You have to rewrite this code as little changes

```
<tr>
<td style="width:200px;"><div class="label"><label><b >Email ID</b></label></div></td>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input" size="40" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) { echo $_SESSION['email']; } ?>" readonly> <br /> <br />

</tr>
```

Don't use `GET method` for passing email

Please try

Comment: the email id doesnt get posted to form.php

Comment: please follow my instruction. Just have a try

Comment: @user3675208, Have you fixed. How it is. You must ensure the session start() is must to write before use.

Answer (score 0):

**Login.php**

```
session_start();//Start the session at the top
include('db.php');
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{          
    if($_POST['action']=="login")
    {

        $email =mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['password']);
        $_SESSION['email']=$email;
echo $_SESSION['email'];//ad this line and tell me are you getting in the login.php. its just to check weather you got value or not
```

In **form**

Start the session at the top.

Thats your `input email`

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input" size="40" value="<?php 

if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) { echo $_SESSION['email']; } ?>" readonly> <br /> <br />
```

Comment: It is not working..the value doesnt get posted to form.php from login.php.. And even the values doesnt get updated to the db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64216/discussion-between-user3675208-and-arif-suhail-123).